# Remove line 1 in a batch file

Tags: batch-file

I am building a code language on batch, and I'm missing a way to remove the first line of a txt file. This is what I've got so far:

```
FOR /F "tokens=* skip=1" %A in ('type "%filename%") do @echo    %%A>> %destinationfile%
```

but that doesn't work for some reason. How do I do that?

Comment: I spot one syntax error (the missing `'` in the parentheses) and perhaps another error if you're actually writing that in a batch file (the `%A` would have to be `%%A` then). So, could you please explain what you mean with »doesn't work«? Also note that `for /f` will skip empty lines (which means it may strip a lot more lines than just the first) and that it can iterate over files just fine without the need for `type`.

Comment: @Jake: my edit has overwritten the additional information you provided (that `findstr /V /R "^$" %filename %` also didn't work. You can of course put it back into the question.

This was of course not intentional, I was not informed you changed something before I submitted my edit. Wanted to sumbit a second edit but was told to leave a comment instead.

Comment: also, to avoid skipping any blank lines, would the syntax work without the /F?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In batch it should be like this :

```
@echo off
set filename=log.txt
set destinationfile=dest.txt
If exist %destinationfile% del %destinationfile%
FOR /F "tokens=* skip=1" %%A in ('type "%filename%"') do (@echo  %%A >> %destinationfile%)
start "" %destinationfile%
```

Comment: Thanks, just what I need.

Comment: @Jake You are welcome ! and don't forgot to upvote it !

Answer (score 2):

```
more +1 %filename% > %destinationfile%
```

is all, you need. See `more /?` for details.

Comment: OK, quick question, what does this actually do, cause, didn't seem to do anything for me

Comment: `more filename` displays the file. `+1` starts with the second line (skips one line). `> outfile.txt` redirects the output to a file - that's why you don't see anything on the screen. Note: `more` will pause after every screen, but if you redirect to a file, it doesn't pause (because that would not make any sense then).

Comment: thanks, i tired that, but it didn't seem to work, what happened was, it copied the Text to another file without the first line. di you know why?

Comment: why? Because of  `+1`. I'm confused now. You said `I'm missing a way to remove the first line of a txt file.`. Now you complain, because it's removing the first line? What did I miss?

Comment: You missed nothing, just I'm trying to modify one single file without having another copy of that file without the first line of Text.

Comment: sorry, no chance, to "edit" a file with batch. You have to write a copy, then delete the original file and rename the copy to the original file name.

Comment: also, how would I be able to rename a file